# How does one limit/constrain user input in Java?

Tags: java, user-input

I want to have an error message appear if a user types more than three integers into the console. So if the console says "Type three integers" and the user types 123 244 242, no matter the numbers size, it should run without a problem. But if the user types 123 244 242 442 then when they press run I would like an error message to appear instead. But not entirely sure how to go about this.

Here is the simple program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type three integers ");
    int firstInt = userInput.nextInt();
    int secondInt = userInput.nextInt();
    int thirdInt = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println(firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What if they enter 3 numbers and then a word?

Comment: You need to write a method which can take a line of text from the user, validate it for correctness (ie numbers only) and re-prompt the user if they do the wrong thing. You should then repeat three times

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstInt = userInput.nextInt();
int secondInt = userInput.nextInt();
int thirdInt = userInput.nextInt();
char run = userInput.next().charAt(0);
if(userInput.hasNext())
{
   System.out.println("Error, you need 3 numbers only, and a char");
   userInput.nextLine(); //clears the rest of the line

}
```

give that a shot and see how it goes. I would suggest having this in a while loop so that it will keep priming for numbers until it gets all of them without error.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   boolean getNumbers = true;
   int firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt;
   Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   while(getNumbers)
   {
      firstInt = userInput.nextInt();
      secondInt = userInput.nextInt();
      thirdInt = userInput.nextInt();
      char run = userInput.next().charAt(0);
      if(userInput.hasNext())
      {
         System.out.println("Error message here");
         userInput.nextLine(); //clear the rest of line
         firstInt = secondInt = thirdInt = 0;
         run = '';
      }
      else
      {
         getNumbers = false;
      }
   }
   //do calculations with numbers here
}
```

Comment: now it's not processing any of the calculations. Thanks though!

Comment: I need to to where once they hit run after typing four rather than three an "Error" message appears instead of the calculations.

Comment: what exactly is stdin I am getting a red squiggle in eclipse for that.

Comment: @user3667054 I defined it above as a Scanner. Sorry, I see that you had it as userInput, I will replace everything to make it less complex to understand.

Comment: I want to have three integers and one char run, but if more than three integers are typed in I need an error message. I didn't think Java would have such a difficult time doing this.

Comment: Ah now when it runs I type three numbers and press enter and nothing else runs. I have a char after it too. I want three numbers and char. But once I have more than three numbers and a char I want an error message.

Comment: Sadly there isnt a nextChar() method of scanner, but you can use the next().charAt(0) to return the first char. the problem is, if the user enters more than one character, it will still work as long as he does not  have more characters after the string. This is the only way I know how to do it with a scanner though, might have to look into a different class. I did edit the post to use the method mentioned though

Comment: I don't know why but this is shocking to me. I am very new to Java. when I thought of programming I thought basically "anything is possible" but even something as simple sounding as limiting the user input isn't there. Makes me wonder how limited the things we can do in Java with this.

Comment: There are so many things in Java though, you just have to navigate and find the right thing for you. I bet if you Google what you want, you can find it. Java is by far my favorite Language, and everything is well documented. Google is your best friend

Comment: So you are saying I could probably find something which would allow me to do that very operation I was asking for? It's just a matter of googling and finding the right combination of code to make that happen?

Comment: most likely, you might have to download a specific API for it, I haven't looked much into it. Java has tons of open source API's though, I'm not gaurenteeing it but I have yet to find something in Java that I have not been able to do, within reason

Comment: Good to know. I am going to have to get use to not understanding and being confused. There is such a vast world to programming in Java. And all langs I'd suppose.